# rake db:migrate doesn't seem to work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two instances of my app: one for development, one for production. My development database is called `snip_development` and my production database is called `snip`.

I've been doing migrations all along in my development environment and it's been going just fine. I recently created a production instance of my app but `rake db:migrate` doesn't seem to have any effect. After I run `rake db:migrate` and log into my database server, I can see that `snip_development` has all the tables I expect it to but `snip` doesn't have any tables at all.

I suspect the problem is that `rake db:migrate` is running on `snip_development` instead of `snip` and that's why I'm not seeing anything happen.

How do I get my migrations to work on my production database?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Sometimes I forget about Google. The answer is this:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: And now, such is the nature of Stack Overflow, this answer is now what you get when you Google. The DELICIOUS irony!!!

Comment: I had the same Issue, But when i run this it shows an error `SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: confirmation_token
`

Comment: I am using `devise` for authentication

Comment: Maybe don't use SQLite in production. I don't think it's meant for that. I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, i too use PostgreSQL now... :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote you every time I revisit this page.

Comment: Thanks - I was banging my head against the wall because I omitted the underscore.

Answer (score 6):

For me the answer above not works. I have to add `bundle exec` to make it works.

```
bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: I think that is because rake used to be an alias for bundle exec rake, but since rails 5 or so the new command is rails db:migrate, the alias for bundle exec rake is determined dynamically. If rails db:migrate still doesn't work, the reason would be that your routes are incorrect or your gemset isn't defined or loaded for the project... wouldn't quote me on that one, this comments is a mix of guessing, changelog reads and something that I used in the past.

Comment: We have more than one version of rails in the server (v.5.2.1 and v.6.0.0), so `rails` command will not work in our context.

Comment: I see, i usually have bash scripts to load each path depending of the project for those cases, but the only real benefit is have access to those methods